# Howto define symbolic tasks with waf?

Tags: makefile, build, waf

I am looking for an alternative for an existing make-based build system that contains multiple tasks for copyiing, packaging, zipping/unzipping actions for various consumers.

Make has 'phony' tasks with a name, that can depend on multiple files that are generated according to rules given in the makefile.

pseudo-code Example in makefile:

```
file123: input1 input2
  zip input1 input2
```

```
filexyz: input11 input12
  zip input11 input12
```

```
.PHONY: command1
command1: file123 filexyz
  copy file123 targetdir
  copy filexyz targetdir
```

executing "make command1", make would generate file123 and filexyz according to the rules given.

command1 is a phony target: there is no real file command1.

How could I define such tasks in waf? I would like to see commands that have files as inputs.